# Wsdl to java and creating stateless session bean

Tags: ejb-3.0

I am working on  a 3 tier architecture environment where the front end is JSP files. The JSP files are purely to get data from user and pass it on to EJB container. The EJB container will have the interface calls to post SOAP XML's to Backend system and acquire response back. I have WSDL file for for XMl formation. How to convert WSDL to Java  and how to write stateless session bean to implement the request XML to post to backend system and get the response back. I want to call the EJB session bean from JSP as Remote access.

Comment: This is a very broad question and is not real;ly asking a coding question. You should consider narrowing your focus and provide code examples of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use standard oracle's JDK wsimport tool. Here is the good link with example www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/